# EC2 + Capistrano: When I deploy a new code to EC2, on website is still displayed an old one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I have a Rails app that is running on EC2 instance. As the deployment tool I am using Capistrano.

When I commit new code (successfully - I see it in the bucket), run `cap deploy` (again, code is successfully deployed, no error) and check the URL of my website, I don't see there the new code, but an old one.

How is that possible? What can be the issue?

**EDIT**: Capistrano output:

```
    /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/mysql in PATH, mode 040777
  * 2013-09-28 12:41:43 executing `deploy'
  * 2013-09-28 12:41:43 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-09-28 12:41:43 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:my_bb_name/my_app_name.git master"
    command finished in 6564ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard fa26f147bfbc8147134177294a248f6a002e6e48 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master git@bitbucket.org:my_bb_name/my_app_name.git /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy fa26f147bfbc8147134177294a248f6a002e6e48; fi"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 3272ms
    copying the cached version to /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159
  * executing "cp -RPp /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/cached-copy /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159 && (echo fa26f147bfbc8147134177294a248f6a002e6e48 > /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/REVISION)"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 2246ms
  * 2013-09-28 12:42:01 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2013-09-28 12:42:01 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159 && bundle install --gemfile /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/Gemfile --path /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 1234ms
  * executing "chmod -R -- g+w /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159 && rm -rf -- /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/public/system && mkdir -p -- /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/public/ && ln -s -- /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/system /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/public/system && rm -rf -- /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/log && ln -s -- /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/log /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/log && rm -rf -- /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/tmp/ && ln -s -- /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/shared/pids /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 523ms
  * executing "find /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/public/images /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/public/stylesheets /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201309281042.03 -- {} ';'; true"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 473ms
  * 2013-09-28 12:42:03 executing `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing "rm -f /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/current &&  ln -s /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/releases/20130928104159 /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/current"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 291ms
 ** transaction: commit
  * 2013-09-28 12:42:04 executing `deploy:restart'
  * executing "kill -s USR2 `cat /home/my_user_name/my_app_name/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin`"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 277ms
```

**EDIT2:** I was thinking if there couldn't be something wrong with unicorn tasks in `deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :deploy do

  task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do 
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{unicorn_cmd} -c #{unicorn_config} -E #{rails_env} -D"
  end
  task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do 
    run "kill -QUIT `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
  end

  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -s USR2 `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
  end

end
```

Comment: you could check clearing your browser cache

Comment: could you paste output of Capistrano? What if you connect to your instance maybe there is a file containing the commit id you are deploying `your_app/current/REVISION`

Comment: Guys, I added Capistrano output. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With [Capistrano Unicorn](https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn) was this problem solved within 5 minutes.